# Strange Javascript code displays wrong number

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, browser, numbers

I've found this Javascript code on the internet, but I cannot figure out why it displays an unexpected number:

```
var foo = 5;
var bar = 7;
fоo = bar;
bar += +!(foo - 5);
console.log(foo = bar); // It displays 8 instead of 7
```

As I understand, we defined two variables `foo` and `bar` which have values `5` and `7` respectively. After that, we copy value from `bar` to `foo`. On the fourth line, `bar` is not incremented, because `+!(7 - 5) == +!2 == +false == 0`. On the last line, value from `bar` is again copied to `foo` and then displayed, which means that `foo` must be `7`. But, why console logs `8` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `fоo = bar;` actually assigns the value of `bar` to a newly created global variable `fоo` — that’s Latin lower-case `F`, *Cyrillic* lower-case letter `O` and Latin lower-case `O`.

If you replace `fоo = bar;` by `foo = bar;` (actually copy paste it), it’ll work as expected.

You can debug this yourself by experimenting with the code in the console and ultimately by typing this in the console:

```
"fоo = bar;".split("").map(function(a){
  return a.charCodeAt(0);
});
/*
** Returns:
** [
**   102,  // "f"
**   1086, // "o"? This seems suspicious!
**   111,  // "o"
**   32,   // " "
**   61,   // "="
**   32,   // " "
**   98,   // "b"
**   97,   // "a"
**   114,  // "r"
**   59    // ";"
** ]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. In your code, this line is the trick:

f**о**o = bar;

The o is not an actual o character. Replace it and you will see.